# Dojo && logical operator

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to set up an if, else if, statement to check if a select option has a value and class. I'm not very experienced in dojo nor javascript.

```
 function openPdf(){
if (dojo.byId("resortDD").value != "") && (dojo.byID("resortDD").class == "") window.open("https://example01.pdf")
else if (dojo.byId("resortDD").value != "") && (dojo.byID("resortDD").class == "charts") window.open("https://example02.pdf")
```

}

The reason I'm also checking the value is because there's another situation when the value could be blank.

```
<SELECT id="resortDD" onchange="showImageForResort()">
<OPTION value="">--- Select a Resort ---</option>
<OPTION value="ma" class="">Williamsburg, Virginia</OPTION>
<OPTION value="my" class="charts">Washington, D.C.</OPTION></SELECT>
```

Comment: What is going wrong with your current code? Does it produce an error or an incorrect result?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be checking `className` instead of `class`.  While `class` is the attribute that is set, it manifests on JavaScript DOM objects via the `className` property.